# how to open system date, sound, display properties in linux?

Tags: linux, qt

I know there are APIs in windows like "desk.cpl", "timedate.cpl" , "sndvol".
I use these in system command to open from a SLOT.
I want to know about these alternatives for Linux.

Please help me is there any command to open these 3 from terminal I only want to show this.

Comment: Sorry, no Linux user can answer to this question. Those "things" are nothing you can "open"... What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: which linux flavour you are using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute following command in terminal

```
gnome-control-center display
gnome-control-center datetime
gnome-control-center sound
```

Comment: And if the desktop is _not_ gnome?

Comment: The OP apparently thinks that answering to questions is nothing worth bothering with ;-)

Comment: @arkascha: It depends on desktop environmnet :)

Answer (score 0):

As a Linux user I do not know what those MS-Windows "things" you mention actually do and you appear to take that for granted. So I have to *guess* here:

- to get the current system time on shell level you can use `date`. See the man page for details: `man date`.
- for the current volume setting, not easy to answer, since Linux is a very modular system. Most likely you could ask DBus about that, but this really depends on what desktop environment  and what sound system you use. You might try `amixer get PCM|tail -n1|sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\1/'`, but as said that really depends...

No idea what "desk.cpl" does, so I cannot say anything about this "thing".